# symbolic icons for nemo

Tags: nautilus, nemo

Is it possible to change nemo (source code probably?) in order to use symbolic icons in the sidebar instead of the usual folder icons, just like nautilus does?

I.e.: I want nemo to use `folder-downloads-symbolic.svg` instead of `folder-downloads.svg` in the "places" panel

Comment: It would be easier to use another theme/modify a existing one. For instance, the Lubuntu theme uses symbolic icons for small icons, whilst most gnome* themes don't.